# What is the solution to this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $$\frac{d}{dt}(y'/y^2)=-\frac{{x'}^2+{y'}^2}{y^3},$$ where $x,y$ are the functions of $t$.  Also ${x'}^2+{y'}^2$=$y^2$ Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Can you at least take the derivative on the left?

Comment: It is from a differential geometry and hyperbolic plane problem, if the result is right the solutions should be the equation of a line and a equation of circle.But so far I just got 2${y'}^2$-y''y=$y^2$, which seems not the expected result

Comment: That looks good to me so far. Solve it for $y(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $x'^2+y'^2 = y^2$, then it reduces to $\frac{d}{dt}(y'/y^2) = -\frac{1}{y}$

So $yy''-2y'^2+y^2=0$

On a whim, let's assume $y = \frac{1}{v}$

Then $y' = -\frac{v'}{v^2}$ and $y'' = \frac{2v'^2-vv''}{v^3}$

If we substitute this into our original equation, we get

$\frac{2v'^2-vv''}{v^4}-2\frac{v'^2}{v^4}+\frac{1}{v^2} = 0$

Simplify (remembering $v$ can't be zero by assumption) to get

$v-v''=0$

So $y(t) = (c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t})^{-1}$

From there, you can solve for $x$.

Comment: Simpler than mine ! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Taking into account the second diffrential equation, the first on write $$\frac{d}{dt}\Big(\frac{y'}{y^2}\Big)=-\frac{1}{y}$$ Differentiating the lhs with respect to $t$, this becomes $$\frac{y''}{y^2}-\frac{2 y'^2}{y^3}=-\frac{1}{y}$$ $$y y''-2 y'^2+y^2=0$$ Changing variable $y=e^z$, the differential equation becomes $$z''-z'^2+1=0$$ Defining $p=z'$, it becomes $$p'-p^2+1=0$$ which is separable since you can write $$\frac{dx}{dp}=\frac{1}{1-p^2}$$ which gives $$x+c=\frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{1+p}{1-p}\Big)$$ that is to say $$p=\frac{e^{2 x+d}-1}{e^{2 x+d}+1}$$

I am sure that you can take from here and arrive to $y$.

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Note that $\ds{{y' \over y^{2}} = -\pars{1 \over y}'}$
and $\ds{-\,{x'^{2} + y'^{2} \over y^{3}} = -\,{1 \over y}}$. Both identities lead to:
\begin{align}
\pars{\totald[2]{}{t} - 1}{1 \over y\pars{t}}=0\quad\imp\quad
\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over y\pars{t}} = A\expo{t} + B\expo{-t}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{A\ \mbox{and}\ B}$ are constants.

Comment: @Joseph I'm glad you like it. Thanks.